# Selecting Picker items text the details in textfields and save

Tags: iphone, text, save, uipickerview

I keep 3 items in picker, by selecting the first picker item I want the text in text fields, respectively after want to save the data. I don't how to write the code to save the data in appdelegate class in -

```
(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hi just check this link you will find the demo example their. [Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html

and for the store data in appdelegate //
in .h
@interface Hiar_Style_NewAppDelegate :
{
NSString *strselect;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strselect;

in .m 
@synthesize strselect;

and whenever you want to use it just make delegate  of app deegate file like this 

Hiar_Style_NewAppDelegate *objappdel=(Hiar_Style_NewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


and use that object like this

objappdel.strselect=@"";
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. i kept pickerview exactly by selecting  but i need the code to save the data.

Comment: ohhk so in which you want to store selected data??

Comment: by selecting the picker item i have to text the details in textfields  and save ( automatically  code goes to app delegate class)
- (void)save{
    //[self categorySelection];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: ohk so in this method 
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{ //write your textfiled name.text instead of mlabel.text and also you can save that textfield value in appdelegate object string so easily you can pass their
//now call the appdelegate object and its method  like
[objappdel save];
//and pass the value
}

Comment: hi kartik, if possible, can u provide your mail id ?

Comment: k sure.
arorakartik1004@yahoo.com

Comment: Kartik do reply  for my mail.

Comment: hey its wrkng bt u want to store data permanently so when app close and run its will b their ??

Comment: Yes i need automatically saves